# nested class as testing method in Java

Tags: java, static, nested-class

```
//: innerclasses/TestBed.java
// Putting test code in a nested class.
// {main: TestBed$Tester}

public class TestBed {
  public void f() { System.out.println("f()"); }
  public static class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestBed t = new TestBed();
      t.f();
    }
  }
} /* Output:
f()
*///:~
```

I am studying "Think in Java". I am just wondering why the above code doesn't work which should be a way to test each class, and can be removed by deleting TestBed$Tester.class file.

The error msg instructs there should be a public static void main(String[] args) in TestBed class as program entry.

java compile version: javac 1.7.0_40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` method must be in the public top-level class. That is the one with the same name as the java-file. Here, that's the `TestBed`-class.

The current `main` method is in an inner class (namely `TestBed$Tester`), and can't be used to start a program.

EDIT: I may have been wrong. I took a look in the book you mentioned, and it looks like you're able to run the inner class from the [Command Promt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) by writing:

```
java TestBed$Tester
```

Comment: I know ...but this code is from "Think in Java, 4th ED". I just wanna know the reason why it taught us this approach.

Comment: @shanwu I have updated my answer. (Not sure if you were notified by my previous comment as it got deleted)

Comment: #~/java_practice/innerclasses$ javac TestBed.java 
#~/java_practice/innerclasses$ java TestBed$Tester
error: In TestBed can't find main method...
   public static void main(String[] args)

what is your java compiler version? I don't know if this has something to do with java compiler version...

Comment: Try `TestBed\$Tester` instead of `TestBed$Tester`. If you're using Unix/Linux, you need to escape the `$` like that.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot! for unix/linux, we should run this inner class test program like this
#java TestBed\$Tester